# How to properly dispose objects created with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, dispose, idisposable

I have the following method which creates instances of objects that are disposable.

```
Public Overridable Sub TransformXmlDocumentsToFileStream(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream, ByVal xmlDocuments As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal transformContext As XslTransformContext)
    Dim readers As IEnumerable(Of XmlReader) = _
        (From document In xmlDocuments _
         Select XmlReader.Create(New System.IO.StringReader(document)))

    With transformContext
         TransformXmlDocumentsToFileStream(stream, readers, transformContext)
    End With
End Sub
```

I then iterate over the objects in another method:

```
For Each reader In readers
    Using reader
        transform.Transform(reader, writer)
    End Using
Next
```

The visual studio code analyzer is giving the warning:

> CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'TransformHelper.TransformXmlDocumentsToFileStream(Stream, IEnumerable(Of String), XslTransformContext)', object 'New StringReader(document)' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'New StringReader(document)' before all references to it are out of scope.

Since there is no reference to the `StringReader`, I cannot put it in a using block or otherwise dispose it.  Is it OK to just ignore this warning?  The `StringReader` should be disposed when the reader goes out of scope and is garbage collected, correct?

Comment: In this specific case, the reader can be closed within the using block, thus closing the underlying stream.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598228/do-i-need-to-force-a-dispose-after-a-linq-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the answer in c#.  A simple way to manage IDisposables is to make the method that calls new, also call Dispose.

```
List<StringReader> stringReaders = new List<StringReader>();
  //note: Select is deferred.  stringReaders is captured.
IEnumerable<XmlReader> readers =
  xmlDocuments.Select(document =>
  {
    StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(document);
    stringReaders.Add(sr);
    return XmlReader.Create(sr);
  });
try
{
  //this method enumerates readers, causing all of the allocations.
  TransformXmlDocumentsToFileStream(stream, readers, transformContext);
}
finally
{
  foreach(StringReader x in stringReaders)
  {
    x.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: No worries about the C#, I know it well.  I wish I could use it in my environment.  It's too bad their isn't an event (OnSelect or OnEnumerate) that could be hooked into so that disposal could happen during iteration.  Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Dispose` is called when the object happens to be garbage collected, that might be never or a very long time after the object falls out of scope. You should Dispose your `StringReader`s explicitly.

If I get my VB right you can do like this

```
    Dim stringReaders As IEnumerable(Of System.IO.StringReader) = _
        (From document In xmlDocuments _
         Select New System.IO.StringReader(document)).ToList()

    Try
        Dim readers As IEnumerable(Of XmlReader) = _
            (From stringReader In stringReaders _
             Select XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        With transformContext
            TransformXmlDocumentsToFileStream(stream, readers, transformContext)
        End With

    Finally
        For Each stringReader In stringReaders
            stringReader.Dispose()
        Next
    End Try
```

Comment: I could be wrong here, but wouldn't the finally you propose recreate all the string readers because this is the second time looping over the enumerable? I believe @David B's solution precludes this by storing the readers in a separate list.

Comment: @Richard, No, the `.ToList()` makes sure the creation is only done once.

Comment: Ah yes sorry. I did not see that and was not thinking about it because I am specifically trying not to do that.  In this case, xmlDocuments is itself another IQueryable over a dataReader (I wrote an IEnumerable/IEnumerator wrapper for dataReader).    I do not want to get all the documents in a list at once so that I do not allocate a big block of memory.