# Do I need to force a Dispose after a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection, idisposable

My DBA says that there are way too many connection open and he thinks it is my code in .net that is leaving them open.

I am using LINQ querys and EF code first.

Example Method:

```
 public List<Stuff> GetStuff()
 {
      var db = new DBContext();

      var results =  db.stuff.toList();

      return results;
 }
```

Do I need to dispose the db var once I am done?  My understanding is that I didn't need to in EF and LINQ.  Please point me to a Microsoft documentation about managing connection in code or best practices for LINQ/EF and db connections

**Update:**

I added

```
db.Connection.Close();
db.Dispose();
```

and I still see the open connection in SQL after the two lines were executed. Is there a reason why it wouldn't close when I force it to close?

Comment: If it's `IDisposable` it's good practise to wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: I went back to all my code and wrapped it in a using statement. Then I realized that I was doing lazy loading.  This does not work well with lazy loading. SO I went back and reverted all the code and rely on have the DataContext for managing the connections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default DbContext automatically manages the connection for you. So you shouldn't have to explicitly call Dispose.

Blog post on the subject: [Link](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

But I believe not disposing can cause performance issues if you're processing a lot of requests. You should add a using statement to see whether or not it's causing a problem in your case.

Answer (score 25):

You should listen to your DBA! Yes, use a `using`. Do not leave connections open unnecessarily. You should connect, do your business with the db, and close that connection, freeing it up for another process. This is especially true in high volume systems.

Edit. Let me further explain with my own experiences here. In low volume processing, it probably isn't an issue, but it's a bad habit not to dispose of something explicitly or not-wrap it in a `using` when it clearly implements `IDisposable`.

In high-volume situations, this is just asking for disaster. Sql server will allot so many connections per application (can be specified in the connection string). What happens is processes will spend time waiting for connections to free up if they're not promptly closed. This generally leads to timeouts or deadlocks in some situations.

Sure, you can tweak Sql server connection mgmt and such, but everytime you tweak a setting, you're making a compromise. You must consider backups running, other jobs running, etc. This is why a wise developer will listen to their DBA's warnings. It's not always all about the code...

Comment: I added db.Connection.Close() and db.Dispose() but the connection remains open in SQL??  I know that there are no other calls to the db it is like the first lines of code and I am the only user that connects to the db.

Comment: Didn't downvote. Didn't upvote either because this totally ignores the fact that by default, EF already closes a connection after each separate database interaction. You can have contexts alive for hours (though that's not sensible) without having any open connections. So *if* `DbContext` is used, there's not other option than "leaving connection mgmt up to the DbContext".

Comment: This msdn post for EF6 and later seems to indicate that connections do remain open until `Dispose()` is called... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849.aspx (At the end of the article, see where it talks about EF6 and later)

Comment: That's about offering an open connection to a context or opening a connection from the calling code. In that case EF will never close it (when connection received) or on context dispose (when opened by calling code). This is to support scenarios where e.g. EF and legacy code should operate in one transaction. So it only happens when the developer explicitly chooses to do so. So while `using` is good practice, in standard scenarios closing connections when working with EF is not necessary.

Comment: @didaxi, first thing I thought to do was going back and close the connection and wrap it around a using. But then it broke a few of my views because in the views it requires lazy loading and if the context have been disposed, then it cannot reconnect to grab the child data.  So Before I listen to my DBA or go ahead with YES use a using. We needed more information how the app was developed and what technology was being used.  The OLD ado.net we would close the connection programmatically but with the new EF datacontext we were relying and trusting that it will handle it for us.

Answer (score 11):

I just asked this [same question over on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273704/best-practice-for-mvc-ef#273705).  Robert Harvey gave a great answer.

> In general, you don't need to use Using statements with Entity Framework data contexts. Lazy collections is one of the reasons why.

I encourage you to read the entire answer on Programmers.SE as well as the links Robert provides in the answer.

Comment: OP is using .`toList()`

Answer (score 5):

The entity framework uses, as far as i know, [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default to reduce the overhead of creating new connections everytime.
Are the connections closed when you close your application?

If so, you could try to decrease the Max Pool Size in your connection string or disable connection pooling entirely. 
See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for a reference of possible options in your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your method defines a Unit of Work; no, if something more primitive. (P.S. something somewhere in your code should define a Unit of Work, and that thing should be wrapped in a `using (var context = new DbContext()) {}` or equivalent.)

And if you belong to the school of thought that your `DbContext` *is* your Unit of Work, then you'll always be wrapping that bad boy with a `using` block: the local caching of data previously fetched during the context lifetime together with the `SaveChanges` method act as a sort of lightweight transaction, and your `Dispose` (without calling `SaveChanges`) is your Rollback (whereas your `SaveChanges` is your Commit).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, here's a standard protocol on how to use IDisposable objects.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

It says:

"As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement."

As they have access to unmanaged resources, you should always consider a "using" statement.